# How to check multiple columns for a value, but if the column is null then dont care about it

Tags: sqlite

person1,person2,person3,status1,status2,status3 where status could either be 'Not done' or 'Done', or null if there isnt any value as there isnt any person associated with it. I am trying to query the table for a row if any one of the status has a value of 'Not done', however if the status column is null then i do not want it to affect my query and the row will not show if all the other statuses are done already.

```
                                         EXAMPLE DATA
                  PK| person1 | person2 | person3 | status1 | status2 | status3
                  1      A         B         C       Done       Done    Not Done
                  2      A         B        NULL     Done       Done      NULL

       select * from table where not (status1 = 'Done' and status2 = 'Done' and status3 = 'Done')
```

I have tried the above query to get rows if there are statuses that are 'Not Done', but as there isnt any person3 in row 2 which means status3 will be null then the row will still show even if status1 and status2 are done already, but i need it to not show in my result set and only row1 should be showing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for rows with a `'Not Done'` in one of the status columns... check for that value, not something else.

```
SELECT * FROM TEST WHERE status1 = 'Not Done'
                      OR status2 = 'Not Done'
                      OR status3 = 'Not Done';
```

```
PK          person1     person2     person3     status1     status2     status3   
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
1           A           B           C           Done        Done        Not Done
```

(Though your query will also only return that first row, not the second, due to how `NULL` works...)